# SQL Server Linked Server Issues

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have installed SQL Server 2000 on two different laptops (laptop 'A' and laptop 'B'). 'A' should connect to 'B' after creating a linked server connection on 'A'.

This step goes well but when I open the query analyzer trying on 'A' to do a select statement from one of the databases of 'B' , I get this error

> SQL Server does not exist or access denied

The weird part is that when I try to run the statement after a while it works fine and it returns the expected results. Waiting another bit, then trying to run the statement, I get the same error again.

Both laptops are connected to a WIFI access point.

Any help is much much appreciated .

Comment: WiFi. Db Connections. Nooooooo. Seriously - there's nothing strange about packet loss and WiFi connections failing. And SQL Server 2000 is older than WiFi. Even if newer versions can handle intermittent connection loss, that old version couldn't

Comment: It looks more like general network issue to me. I would assign static IP addresses to your laptops and link SQL server by IP address. Of course such setup would work only in static network context - using always same wifi router/ap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your suggested solutions. I tried Ethernet connection instead and the linked server connection works perfectly .